# Where to see the existing references to assemblies in a web application in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, reference, .net-4.5

I have few web applications in Visual Studio 2012 which are IIS Web Applications. I am unable to find the list of already added referenced assemblies to the web application.

I need to check the versions of those and need to confirm whether they are getting updated when the other project's are rebuilt in the solution, but other than the direct Project DLLs in the `\bin` folder, I can't find a list of references anywhere like in other project types.

**And if there is no such list, then how will I find whether a particular DLL present in the `Web Application's Bin` folder was added via `Add Reference` or was directly copied into it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have VS 2012 at work but in VS 2010 what you can do is either:

1. Unload the web application project (right click on the project, unload) and then right click, edit. You'll then see a list of all references.
2. Alternativly, open the windows folder where your project exists and open your project file (.csproj) in notepad++ (or equivalent).

Hope I've understood your question correctly!

Comment: Yes, you have understood correctly. I knew these two methods, but I was thinking that like other type of projects as we get a References folder which expands to show all existing references.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's the same, but in VS 2013 you right click on the Project -> Property Pages, then select References on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you my code stripped out, so it's not "ready" solutoin, but the assumption is you know the list of main assemblies and you want to know if any referenced by those assemblies are missing

```
    private void PopulateReferencedButMissingAssemblies(List<string> listOfKnowAssymblies)
    {
        HashSet<string> missingRefs = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (string assemblyName in listOfKnowAssymblies)
        {
            Assembly parent = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
            AssemblyName[] refs = parent.GetReferencedAssemblies();

            foreach (AssemblyName d in refs) //checking references
            {
                try
                {
                    Assembly subRef = Assembly.Load(d.FullName);
                    subRef = null; //release loaded assembly
                }
                catch
                {
                    missingRefs.Add(d.FullName);
                }
            }
        }

        if (missingRefs.Count == 0)
        {
            //refsPanel.Visible = false;
            //return;
        }


        foreach (string mref in missingRefs)
        {
            //display missing refs in my case
        }

    }
```